# Remove substrings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substring

How do you remove `, The` from the movie name in Excel?

See the example below:

> $50,000 Climax Show, The

Or also how do you remove the `, A`?

> Bug's Life, A

Answer (score 1):

Find & Select, Replace..., Find what: `, *`, Replace All.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(RIGHT(UPPER(A1),5) = ", THE",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-5),IF(RIGHT(UPPER(A1),3) = ", A",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3),A1))
```